# 'Object' does not contain a method for 'dispose' C# compiler error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to compile and test my code for my homework assignment, and Visual Studio is throwing up errors saying that the 'object' does not contain a method for 'dispose', and I can't figure out why it won't let me compile my code. The assignment reads:

> Rectangle Class: Create a class Rectangle. The class has attributes length and width, each of which default to 1. It has read-only properties that calculate the Perimeter and the Area of the rectangle. It has properties for both length and width. The set accessors should verify that length and width are each floating point numbers greater than 0.0 and less than 20.0. Write an app to test class Rectangle.

Here is the code for the rectangle class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        private float length = 1;
        private float width = 1;

        public Rectangle(float length, float width)
        {
            Length = length;
            Width = width;
        }
        public float Length
        {
            get
            {
                return this.length;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0.0f || value > 20.0f)
                {
                    this.length = 1.0f;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.length = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public float Width
        {
            get
            {
                return this.width;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0.0f || value > 20.0f)
                {
                    this.width = 1.0f;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.width = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public float Perimeter
        {
            get
            {
                return(Length + Width)*2;
            }
        }
        public float Area
        {
            get
            {
                return(Length*Width);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Perimeter is {0:F2} and Area is {1:F2}", Perimeter, Area);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the app to test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
    class TestProgram
    {
        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(19.5f, 15.9f);
            Console.WriteLine(rect);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to compile it, it throws up two errors:

```
Error   1   'WindowsFormsApplication16.Form2.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to 
override    c:\users\kyle\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication16\
WindowsFormsApplication16\Form2.Designer.cs 14  33  WindowsFormsApplication16

Error   2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose'    
c:\users\kyle\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication16\
WindowsFormsApplication16\Form2.Designer.cs 20  18  
WindowsFormsApplication16
```

Here is the code it says the error is located at:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Can anyone possibly shed some light on this and give me an idea as to why it won't compile?

Comment: The last block of code. Is it system generated?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, as the comments themselves say.

Comment: If the form is not necessary in the project then you can remove it for now and see if things are working fine. That you would be sure that if it's the form only or something else behind breaking the things.

Comment: Where your main Form is created? Usually that happens in Main -  but yours is completely different from the standard one.

Comment: The declaration of the class `Form2` inside file `Form2.cs` is missing the `: Form` part of `class Form2: Form`

Comment: Does from inherits other class in the main code behind?

Comment: I'm guessing that `IContainer` doesn't inherit from `IDisposable` or doesn't otherwise define `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

That Form2 has to derive from a class...I think it should be "Form". Create a new project / add a new Form and see the class from which it derives. You probably deleted it by accident.

Comment: It's a partial class.  The base class is defined in the other file.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this error recently when I was importing a form into a project.

The error came after importing the form, I changed the namespace on the main.cs code file, but I did not change the namespace for the corresponding designer.cs file.  When I matched the namespaces, the error messages went away.